# how to make a bat file to delete all hidden and non hidden files from a folder

Tags: windows, directory, hidden, delete-file, invisible

My question is how to make a bat file that deletes all files, hidden and non hidden from a folder, this is my script so far:

```
cd "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents"
del . /Q
```

the problem is that it only deletes the visible files, not the ones hidden.

could someone please contribute a script that will delete both hidden AND standard visible files, I would prefer this script to be in

```
.bat
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```dos
del /a /q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\*"
```

`del` command includes the `/a` switch to allow filtering by file attributes (see `del /?` for a list of available switches and options). If you include the switch but don't indicate any attribute, all files are selected.

Answer (score 0):

`del` will not delete the hidden files

`del /A:H` will delete only the hidden files

`del /A will` delete both the hidden and non-hidden files